# Asset Libraries are not showing under 'File Path' in preferences... Help

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, asset-browser, asset

I am trying to use the biome reader addon which requires me to use asset libraries and stuff (first time). However, when I enter preferences - file paths, I don't see any options for asset libraries. [image]

Any ideas? I can't find anything on the internet showing where to find it.

Comment: Hello. What version of Blender are you running ?